# jQuery clash on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, highcharts

I put together a script that works a charm in Chrome and that, for some reason, refuses to work properly in Internet Explorer 9. The page simply hangs/freezes forever ... and then loads. Likewise, when the user does anything on the page after it has loaded (in this instance loading highcharts by selecting items on dropdown boxes) it will hang/freeze ... and eventually work.

I have tried to debug the page but the freezing makes it very difficult and agonizing. I have had no success identifying the source of the issue. My code loads three libraries and uses one custom script that I put together myself.

Here are the three libraries:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Highstocks/js/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="../Highstocks/js/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

What I do know from my debugging efforts:

(1) The page refuses to load properly in IE whether I include my custom code or not.

(2) I have tried to remove my libraries one by one. When I remove jquery-ui.min.js the page loads normally. Obviously can't do much with it at that point though ... :-) I have tried loading different versions of jQuery and jQuery UI with no success.

Does anybody have a clue as to what I can do to overcome this bottleneck?

Comment: Try putting the highstock JS's at he bottom of the HTM page. As i remember from their examples they had them at the bottom. They would load last before anything else.

Comment: I see you're including _highstock.js_ but not _highcharts.js_. Do you need to include _highcharts.js_ to make _highcharts-more.js_ work?

Comment: comment out the scripts one by one starting from the bottom to help pinpoint what is causing the hang.

Comment: Try to downgrade jquery, because since 2.x jquery required migration plugin for old browser. Live demo will be helpful.